# How to link a page using live-template and text-data

Tags: links, wiki, confluence

I'm totally new in the field of confluence and i have a problem i obviously can not solve on my own.

Building up my wiki i created a live-template so i can make sure every page has got the same structure. Within this live-template i use text-data to make it more comfortable for the end user to edit the text. One of these text-data fields is only used to link to other pages. The links work so far. But if i change the name of a linked page, the link does not update. If i do the same without using a text-data field, the link updates no matter how often i change the name of the linked page.

Is there anyone there who can help me on that one?!

Have an nice week,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

When pages are renamed Confluence will try to change the links in all pages to reflect the new name. This does not work for scaffolding data as scaffolding stores data in a different location to page data such that the relinking function is not applied.